# How to query the oldest app engine versions on GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I've been trying to write a script to remove old App Engine Versions on GCP. Ideally we only want to keep the 60 newest App Engine Versions and remove the rest.

After some research, I've came up with a script like this:

```
VERSIONS_TO_REMOVE=$(gcloud app versions list --service=default --filter="TRAFFIC_SPLIT=0" --sort-by ~LAST_DEPLOYED --format='value(version.id)' | tail -n +60)

if [ ${#VERSIONS_TO_REMOVE} -gt 0 ]
 then
   for VERSION in $VERSIONS_TO_REMOVE; do
     gcloud app versions delete "$VERSION" --service=default --quiet
   done
fi
```

and I expect it to keep only the 60 newest versions. However, it has removed the versions ranked lower than 60 if they are sorted by VERSION.ID.

I also tried to print out all sorted versions with the following code, and indeed the versions are sorted by `LAST_DEPLOYED`.

```
ALL_VERSIONS=$(gcloud app versions list --service=default --filter="TRAFFIC_SPLIT=0" --sort-by ~LAST_DEPLOYED)

echo "${ALL_VERSIONS}"
```

So I'm quite confused at this point. Why wouldn't it work that I have added `sort-by`? Why it's sorted nicely in `ALL_VERSIONS` but not `VERSIONS_TO_REMOVE`? It would be super helpful if you could provide some insights on it, thank you!

Comment: echo VERSIONS_TO_REMOVE and confirm it actually only lists the newest 60 versions (and not all your versions)

Comment: Have you tried community member suggestion in above comment?